# validate form and submit to same page

Tags: php, jquery, validation, form-submit

I am trying to get the form not to submit to send_email.php, but to stay on the same page. Also, I would like the errors to show under the input boxes. (I think I can do the errors if I understand how to keep the page from refreshing)

I have been reading all over stackoverflow that I should use AJAX for it, but I have no idea how to start.

form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_email.php">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

send_email.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "example@example.com";
$email_subject = "Form Subject";


function died($error) {
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']))
 {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // required


$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'Enter a valid email.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'Enter a valid name.<br />';
}
if(strlen($telephone) != NULL || strlen($telephone) != "") {
$error_message .= 'Enter valid phone.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>


<b>Thank you!</b>. 

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {

var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();


$.post("send_email.php", { "name": name,"email": email,"phone": phone},
 function(data){

alert( data.response + data.email);

 }, "json");
return false;
});
});
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

==========================================================================

**send_email.php will look like this**

```
<?php

$email_to = $_POST['email'];
$email_subject = "Form Subject";


$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = "example@example.com"; // required
$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // required


$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'Enter a valid email.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'Enter a valid name.<br />';
}
if(strlen($telephone) != NULL || strlen($telephone) != "") {
$error_message .= 'Enter valid phone.<br />';
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message = "Name:" . $_POST['name'] . " Mail:".$_POST['email'] ." Phone:". $_POST['phone'];




// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if(@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
echo '{ "response": "SENT", "email": "'.$_POST['email'].'"}'; 
}else{
echo '{ "response": "ERROR", "email": "'.$_POST['email'].'"}'; 
}



?>
```

you could validate your form with jquery, i deleted some unnecessary validation lines from your php so you can add later again when you sure your codes work, and mail_to address was not pointed to form mail address.

i checked above code and it works. Good luck.

note:in my server if(@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))  always return true even if i use blank as email address

Comment: Works in Opera, doesn't work in explorer or firefox, email is sent but with blank fields in Chrome and safari... any ideas on that?

Comment: I changed php file you can use revised to fix blank mail.

Comment: Travis now it works on firefox chrome internet explorer and others, use revised files above.

Comment: Still a bit strange. Opera works perfectly. IE is not working at all, Chrome, FF, and Safari all send the mail but the message only shows Name: Mail: Phone:.  So I tried to change $email_message = "Name:" . $_POST['name'] . " Mail:".$_POST['email'] ." Phone:". $_POST['phone'];  to  $email_message = "Name:" . $first_name . " Mail:".$email_from ." Phone:". $telephone;  But still no messages.... contact forms sure are a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

$.post('send_email.php', $('#theform').serialize())
 //where theform is id of the form you want to submit..

You can find more options available on the following link

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. Here we are not using ajax but are using sessions.

**form.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_email.php">
    <table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_name]; ?></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="2"><?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_email]; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="2"><?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_phone]; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </form>
<?php
 $_SESSION[lmsg_name] ='';
 $_SESSION[lmsg_email] ='';
 $_SESSION[lmsg_phone] =''; 
?>
```

**send_email.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "example@example.com";
$email_subject = "Form Subject";


function died($error) {
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']))
 {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // required



$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message = 'Enter a valid email.<br />';
$_SESSION[lmsg_email] = $error_message;
header("Location:form.php");
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message = 'Enter a valid name.<br />';
$_SESSION[lmsg_name] = $error_message;
header("Location:form.php");
}
if(strlen($telephone) != NULL || strlen($telephone) == "") {
$error_message = 'Enter valid phone.<br />';
$_SESSION[lmsg_phone] = $error_message;
header("Location:form.php");
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>


<b>Thank you!</b>. 

<?php
}
?>
```